# Creation Variations of Pandas DataFrame with Column Dependencies

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to expand my DataFrame to incorporate other scenarios. For example, for a DataFrame capturing active users per company, I want to add a scenario where active users increase but do not exceed the total user count.

Example input:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

I tried using a loop but quite inefficiently, yielding odd results:

```
    while df[df['active_users'] + add_users <= df['total_users']].any():
            df[(df['active_users'] + add_users) <= df["total_users"]]['active_users'] = (df['active_users'] + add_users).astype(int)
            add_users += 1
```

Comment: Please add your tabular data in text format so others can replicate it. Read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and for counters use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['inactive_users'] + 1)]

df1['inactive_users'] = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)

s = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df1['active_users'] += s

df1['company'] = (df1['company'] + ' + ' + s.astype(str).replace('0','')).str.strip(' +')
print (df1)
  company  contract  total_users  active_users  inactive_users
0       A     10000           10             7               3
0   A + 1     10000           10             8               2
0   A + 2     10000           10             9               1
0   A + 3     10000           10            10               0
1       B      7500            5             4               1
1   B + 1      7500            5             5               0
```